# R divide two dataframes by column

Tags: r, dataframe, division

I have two large dataframes (with 35,000 x 135 dim each) that also contain a lot NA values. What I want is to divide each column from dataframe A with the contents of the previous column of dataframe B. Specifically, for j = rows and i = columns, A(j,2)/B(j,1), A(j,3)/B(j,2), and so on. So, at the end there would be a new dataframe with dim (35,000 x 134).

I have created this code (due to the large dataset unfortunately the dataframes are not replicable here), but is there a more efficient way to do that?

First dataframe named NNF.data is created after I extract from Fund.data every column that contains the word NNF.

```
NNF.data <- Fund.data[ , grep("NNF", names(Fund.data))]
```

Example:

```
    NNF.2005.07.EUR NNF.2005.08.EUR NNF.2005.09.EUR

1          NA             NA              NA
2          NA             NA              NA
3          NA             NA              NA
4       -18,066        -83,044          -1,684
5          NA             NA              NA
6      1,384,196       1,011,219       3,266,810
7          NA             NA              NA
8          NA             NA              NA
9          NA             NA              NA
10      99,092         1,478,996       1,118,067
11    -6,961,028       1,252,678       2,086,868
12    -2,921,427    -285,339,229     289,599,959
```

Similarly for dataframe named AUM.data

```
AUM.data <- Fund.data[ , grep("AUM", names(Fund.data))]
```

Retain the dimensions

```
columns <- dim(AUM.data)[2] # 135
rows <- dim(AUM.data)[1] # 35,000

growth_columns <- columns - 1 # Reduce the size of the columns by 1
Growth.data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = growth_columns, nrow = rows))
# Growth.data dim = 35,000 134
ii <- 1
for(i in 1:growth_columns){
  ii <- ii+1
  Growth.data[ ,i] <- NNF.data[,ii]/AUM.data[,i]
}
```

In return I get a warning

```
In Ops.factor(NNF.data[, k], AUM.data[, i]) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: try `str(Fund.data)`: you don't have `numerics` but `factors` (because of commas) hence it is not possible to compute division.

Comment: Thanks Cath for pointing this out. Should I amend the commas then? Maybe that would be easier.

Comment: Where does your data come from ? (why are there commas?) probably it would be easier to work before importing data in `R`. Else you can try `lapply(Fund.data, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", as.character(x))))` if the only "character items" in your data are commas

Comment: I tried this command and it worked apparently, but since you are the one who gave me the idea would you like to put your comment as answer please? So, I can give the appropriate points?
`NNF.data <- as.data.frame(lapply(NNF.data, FUN = function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))))`

PS: your suggestion was correct but I wanted to work on a data.frame thus I used the aforementioned. Also, the data comes from a mutual fund database

Comment: if all the values in the dataframes are numeric: `as.matrix(A[-1]) / as.matrix(B[-length(B)])`